# How to make an image fit into a simple auto-playing slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

My question is regarding sizing of images into a section, which I think is called a container. Does anybody happen to know how to do this.
I've included the code of the aspects involved.

**HTML**

```
<div id="slideshow">
            <div>
              <img src="Img1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="Img2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
               <img src="Img3.jpg">
            </div>
         </div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

#slideshow {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 22%;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.slideshow {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

#slideshow > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

---

**JS**

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        
        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  3000);
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: First of all you gave slideshow an id and not a class. You are trying to give a height and width to an element which doesn't even exists. I assume `object-fit` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I love your energy man, amazing. :)

You are only couple of lines from the result you want.

One of the errors was that you didnt actually target the `slideshow` div in your `css`, you were targeting it as `.slideshow`, and that is wrong because slideshow is an ID, so you should say `#slideshow` in your `css`.

And the last thing that you gotta do is make your images always fully fit your container, you can do this by using `width : 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;`

Just replace your current `css` with this one, and it should work :)

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}

#slideshow {
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 22%;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

#slideshow {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

#slideshow > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic man. Appreciate the effort of responding!

The images are now properly sized. That one is solved now.

Unfortunately, the slideshow has stopped and it is now displaying 1 of 3 pictures. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure ? Look at my CodePen, everything works properly on my side : https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/VwKzGQg

Comment: I am so noobish. It is working perfectly. Man, thanks a million!!!

Comment: You are welcome ! :) Let me know for anything you need !